# Convert MVC 4 View To Pdf using Itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, itext

I am trying to Convert a MVC 4 View  to a PDF. I have no idea where to start, after searching google i found ItextSharp and have been playing around with it. 
My View is fairly Simple it has a Map and a Table. i would like to just call an action in the controller and have it print my web page. 
Any Advice would be greatly Appreciated

Comment: Even if you fail horribly, it's better to try and show some code then post basically asking for code. Also, have you read the documentation? Include some of the stuff you've read. If you're having trouble understanding code snippets, or something similar, include that as well.

Comment: you can't use Itextsharp like that outside your organization without a license. $$$ . but check [here](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/). google is your friend

Comment: thank you guys, and sorry i am totally new to all of this.for the future i will show my code @Carrie Kendall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa)

```
public ActionResult TestViewWithModel(string id)
{
    var model = new TestViewModel {DocTitle = id, DocContent = "This is a test"};
    return new ViewAsPdf(model);
}

public ActionResult PrintIndex()
{
    return new ActionAsPdf("Index", new { name = "Giorgio" }) { FileName = "Test.pdf" };
}
```

It uses [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) under the hood.

> wkhtmltopdf and wkhtmltoimage are open source (LGPLv3) command line
>   tools to render HTML into PDF and various image formats using the QT
>   Webkit rendering engine. These run entirely "headless" and do not
>   require a display or display service.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response i have been looking into wkhtmltopdf but havent found good examples to go off of. since i have started using mvc only a short while ago

Comment: @Bigman20013 No worries, Rotativa is easy to use and should cover your use case. If the answer solves your problem please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Rotativa doesn't works on shared hosting server.